# How to declare an empty variable inside function in PHP

Tags: php

It sound a Stupid question but I don know what is the problem each time i try to declare a variable inside a function it gives me an error !

```
function emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $password, $confirm_password)
{

    $result;

    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($password) || ($confirm_password)) {
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I've tried to declare it and i got an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a variable like this:

```
$result = NULL;
```

You can try using any of the following:

```
{
    $result = false;
    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($password) || ($confirm_password)) {
        $result = true;
    }
    return $result;
}
// or
{
    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($password) || ($confirm_password)) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
// or
{
    return (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($password) || ($confirm_password));
}
```

All these constructs produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *declare* variables in PHP, you **define** them.

There's no need for `$result;` and it actually means "read the value of the variable `$result` and then do nothing with it" - which will give you an undefined variable error if `$result` isn't defined (which, in your case, it is).

What you have to do instead is initialize `$result` to *some* value, or leave it out completely:

`$result = false;`

For example.

---

Your code can be greatly simplified by just using assigment:

```php
$result = empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($password) || ($confirm_password);
```

No need for the `if`. And you can actually ditch the `$result` variable entirely:

```php
function emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $password, $confirm_password) {
    return empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($password) || ($confirm_password);
}
```